# how to correct convert char to byte in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, byte

I have some problem.
I write next code.

```
z=recv(conn,buff,512,0);//"Hi VahagnAAAAAAA" - but encrypted for example "zЖWЙЇ%ЂАЊ"S]яАAЧ0АбЯ.Щk5S¤Oц", length 32
BYTE messageLen = (BYTE)strlen(buff);// messageLen = 32
BYTE encryptedMessage[32];
memcpy(encryptedMessage, buff, messageLen);//!!!!!!!!!!!
DWORD encryptedMessageLen = messageLen;
CryptDecrypt(hSessionKeyRSA_2,NULL,TRUE,0,encryptedMessage, &encryptedMessageLen);
cout<<encryptedMessage<<endl;
```

I recv to buffer char array 32 length.
Where I copy encrypted text

```
"zЖWЙЇ%ЂАЊ"S]яАAЧ0АбЯ.Щk5S¤Oц"
```

to byte array, on the encryptedMessage have next value

```
"zЖWЙЇ%ЂАЊ"S]яАAЧ0АбЯ.Щk5S¤OцMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM"
```

where I decrypted I don't get start text, I get

```
"Ik VqagnеAAcS]‰МММММММММММ ММММММММ"
```

How I can fix it? please help me.

**UPDATE**

Client main()

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    const char* servername="127.0.0.1";

    Sleep(2000);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    WSADATA wsaData;
    struct hostent *hp;
    unsigned int addr;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int wsaret=WSAStartup(0x101,&wsaData);
    if(wsaret)  
        return 0;
    SOCKET conn;
    conn=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(conn==INVALID_SOCKET)
        return 0;
    if(inet_addr(servername)==INADDR_NONE)
    {
        hp=gethostbyname(servername);
    }
    else
    {
        addr=inet_addr(servername);
        hp=gethostbyaddr((char*)&addr,sizeof(addr),AF_INET);
    }
    if(hp==NULL)
    {
        closesocket(conn);
        return 0;
    }
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=*((unsigned long*)hp->h_addr);
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=htons(20248);
    if(connect(conn,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server)))
    {
        closesocket(conn);
        return 0;   
    }
    std::cout<<"Connected to server";
    char buff[512];
    memset(buff,'\0',512);  
    int z;
    z=recv(conn,(char*)exportRSAKey,140,0);//Import RSA key
    z=recv(conn,(char*)exportAESKey,140,0);//Import AES key
    z=recv(conn,buff,512,0);//Get encryption text
    importKey();//import key to client
    BYTE messageLen = (BYTE)strlen(buff);
    BYTE encryptedMessage[33];
    memcpy(encryptedMessage, buff, messageLen);
    DWORD encryptedMessageLen = messageLen;
    CryptDecrypt(hSessionKeyRSA_2,NULL,FALSE,0,encryptedMessage, &encryptedMessageLen);
    cout<<encryptedMessage<<endl;
//  buff[z]=0;

}
```

Import key to client

```
if (CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv_RSA_2, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV, PROV_RSA_AES, 0))
{
    printf("A cryptographic provider has been acquired.\r\n");
}
else
{
    DWORD d = GetLastError();
    return -1;
}
int iii =  CryptImportKey(hCryptProv_RSA_2,(BYTE *)&exportAESKey,140,NULL,NULL,&hSessionKeyRSA_2);

if(CryptSetKeyParam(hSessionKeyRSA_2, KP_IV, exportRSAKey, 0))
{
    cout<<"ok";

}
```

Server main()

```
std::cout<<"Client connected... "<<pParam<<std::endl;
char buff[512];
CString cmd;
CString params;
int n;
int x;
BOOL auth=false;
SOCKET client=(SOCKET)pParam;
strcpy(buff,"#Server Ready.\r\n");

char keybuff[1024];
createRSAPublicKey();//create enc_dec key
//keybuff = exportRSAKey;
//memset(rec,'\0',512);
const char *p = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(exportRSAKey);
send(client,p,140,0);//send RSA
const char *pp = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(exportAESKey);
send(client,pp,140,0);//Send AES
const char *ppp = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(encryptedMessage);
send(client,ppp,512,0);//Send encrypt text
```

createRSAPublicKey()

```
BOOL createRSAPublicKey()
{
    if (CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv_AES, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV, PROV_RSA_AES, 0))
    {
        printf("A cryptographic provider has been acquired.\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD d = GetLastError();
        return -1;
    }
    HCRYPTKEY hSessionKey_AES;
    if (!CryptGenKey(hCryptProv_AES, CALG_AES_256, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hSessionKey_AES))
    {
        DWORD d = GetLastError();
        return -1;
    }
    // Create RSA key to encrypt AES one
    HCRYPTKEY hSessionKey;
    if (!CryptGenKey(hCryptProv_AES, AT_KEYEXCHANGE, 1024 << 16, &hSessionKey))
    {
        DWORD d = GetLastError();
        return -1;
    }
    // Export key
    DWORD keylen;
    BOOL ok = CryptExportKey(hSessionKey_AES, hSessionKey, SIMPLEBLOB, 0, exportRSAKey, &keylen);
    if (ok == FALSE)
    {
        DWORD d = GetLastError();
        return -1;
    }
    BYTE *encKey = (BYTE *)malloc(keylen);
    ok = CryptExportKey(hSessionKey_AES, hSessionKey, SIMPLEBLOB, 0, exportAESKey, &keylen);
if (ok == FALSE)
    {
        DWORD d = GetLastError();
        return -1;
    }
    else
        printf("A cryptographic key export succeeded.\r\n");


    BYTE messageLen = (BYTE)strlen(mess);
    memcpy(encryptedMessage, mess, messageLen);
    DWORD encryptedMessageLen = messageLen;
    CryptEncrypt(hSessionKey_AES, NULL, TRUE, 0, encryptedMessage, &encryptedMessageLen, sizeof(encryptedMessage)); 

}
```

Comment: You can't encode non-ASCII characters as a single byte.

Comment: oh, but how I can fix it? I don't great know C++ :(

Comment: According to the text could have a problem of forgetting the null terminated character. `strlen` count until the `\0` character if it's missing in the received buffer you need to handle that case.

Comment: @Vahagn You cannot use `cout` that way if the message contains embedded NULLs.  You give `cout` a character buffer, it will stop on the first NULL character.

Comment: Yes of course, in buff = "zЖWЙЇ%ЂАЊ"S]яАAЧ0АбЯ.Щk5S¤Oц", I add to buff[32] = '\0', but don't help :(

Comment: full code https://yadi.sk/d/e0y4Zm7GdKJpb

Comment: @Vahagn No.  Do *not* put a null at the end of encrypted data.  Understand that encrypted data can have nulls in it.  Those nulls are *not* there to terminate the string -- they are part of the data itself.

Comment: @Vahagn - Why do you need to show us a big application when a simple main() program with maybe 10 lines of code showing encrypt/decrypt is all you need?  Maybe that is what you should do -- create a simple main() program where all it does is take a string, encrypts it, and then decrypts it back.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie https://yadi.sk/d/e0y4Zm7GdKJpb

Comment: @Vahagn I don't open links to sites I have no idea about.  Second, and again, how hard is it to just put together a main() program, hard-code a string, call your encryption function, show the results, and then call your decrypt function?  We don't have to know that you call `recv()` or any of the other unnecessary information.  Not only will it help us more, it will help you more  in focusing on the real issue.

Comment: BTW, I don't understand your question of converting a char into a byte.  There is nothing to convert -- a char is an 8-bit value. What I do see is that you're putting nulls to terminate an ecrypted string, which is wrong (if not unnecessary), and that you didn't use `cout` correctly to output a char array that is *not* null terminated.

Comment: UPDATE, add client and server main function and export import key pare function

Comment: I fix it. `BYTE messageLen = (BYTE)strlen(buff);
  BYTE encryptedMessage[512];
  encryptedMessage[messageLen]='\0';
  memcpy(encryptedMessage, buff, messageLen);
  DWORD encryptedMessageLen = messageLen;
  `

Comment: @Vahagn You have memory leaks in your updated code.  You call `malloc` without a call to `free`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `strlen()` to get the length of `buff`, but `recv()` does not null-terminate the buffer unless a null terminator was actually transmitted and read.  You should instead be using the return value of `recv()`, which is the number of bytes actually read:

```
z=recv(conn,buff,512,0);
messageLen = z;//(BYTE)strlen(buff);
```

That being said, TCP is a byte stream, it has no concept of message boundaries.  There is no 1-to-1 relationship between `send()` and `recv()` in TCP, like there is in UDP, so `recv()` above could read as little as 1 byte or as many as 512 bytes, and `buff` could contain a full message, a partial message, pieces of multiple messages, etc.  You can't just blindly read and expect to receive everything in one go.  You need to take all of that into account.

Design your TCP protocol to delimit messages, either with a preceding header that specifies the message length, or a trailing delimiter that never appears in the message body.  Call `recv()` as many times as it takes, buffering any received data, and only process/decrypt complete messages that are in your buffer, leaving partial message data in the buffer to be completed by later reads.

Try something more like this:

Client main()

```
int readBuffer(SOCKET s, void *buffer, int buflen)
{
    unsigned char *pbuf = (unsigned char*) buffer;
    int total = 0;
    while (total < buflen)
    {
        int num = recv(s, pbuf+total, buflen-total, 0);
        if (num < 0)
            return SOCKET_ERROR;
        if (num == 0)
            return 0;
        total += num;
    }
    return total;
}

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    const char* servername="127.0.0.1";

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    WSADATA wsaData;
    memset(&wsaData, 0, sizeof(wsaData));

    int wsaret = WSAStartup(0x101, &wsaData);
    if (wsaret != 0)    
        return 0;

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servername);
    if (server.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
    {
        struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname(servername);
        if (hp == NULL)
            return 0;
        server.sin_addr = *((in_addr*)hp->h_addr);
    }
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(20248);

    SOCKET conn = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (conn == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return 0;

    if (connect(conn, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) != 0)
    {
        closesocket(conn);
        return 0;   
    }

    std::cout << "Connected to server";

    if (readBuffer(conn, exportRSAKey, 140) <= 0) //Import RSA key
    {
        closesocket(conn);
        return 0;   
    }

    if (readBuffer(conn, exportAESKey, 140) <= 0) //Import AES key
    {
        closesocket(conn);
        return 0;   
    }

    importKey();//import key to client

    DWORD messageLen;
    if (readBuffer(conn, &messageLen, sizeof(messageLen)) <= 0) //Get encryption text length
    {
        closesocket(conn);
        return 0;   
    }
    messageLen = ntohl(messageLen);

    std::vector<BYTE> buff(messageLen);
    if (messageLen > 0)
    {
        if (readBuffer(conn, &buff[0], messageLen) <= 0) //Get encryption text
        {
            closesocket(conn);
            return 0;   
        }

        if (!CryptDecrypt(hSessionKeyRSA_2, NULL, FALSE, 0, &buff[0], &messageLen))
        {
            closesocket(conn);
            return 0;   
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::string((char*)buff.data(), messageLen) << std::endl;
}
```

Server main()

```
int sendBuffer(SOCKET s, void *buffer, int buflen)
{
    unsigned char *pbuf = (unsigned char*) buffer;
    int total = 0;
    while (total < buflen)
    {
        int num = send(s, pbuf+total, buflen-total, 0);
        if (num < 0)
            return SOCKET_ERROR;
        if (num == 0)
            return 0;
        total += num;
    }
    return total;
}

...

SOCKET client = (SOCKET)pParam;
std::cout << "Client connected... " << pParam << std::endl;
...
createRSAPublicKey();//create enc_dec key
...
if (sendBuffer(client, exportRSAKey, 140) <= 0) //send RSA
{
    closesocket(client);
    return;
}
if (sendBuffer(client, exportAESKey, 140) <= 0) //Send AES
{
    closesocket(client);
    return;
}
...
DWORD tmpMessageLen = htonl(messageLen);
if (sendBuffer(client, &tmpMessageLen, sizeof(tmpMessageLen)); //Send encrypt text length
{
    closesocket(client);
    return;
}
if (sendBuffer(client, encryptedMessage, messageLen) <= 0) //Send encrypt text
{
    closesocket(client);
    return;
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you, but my compilator get 2 error mess.`'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'unsigned char *''read': identifier not found`